# Associate .env file with vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js

I would like to run different vue.config.js files based on my enviroment. Is it possible to point out a specific vue.config.js in an .env-file? Something like this:

**.env.foo:**

```
VUE_CONFIG=foo.vue.config.js
```

When I run `npm run server -- --mode foo` I want to use the specified vue config.

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI 3? If so, you can take a look at this: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: @ThomasLombart Yes I use CLI 3 and I'm refering to the environment variables. That's not the question here :)

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. I'm not sure that's possible. However, you can, require different configuration files directly from `vue.config.js` based on your environment variable.

Comment: @ThomasLombart Right, I guess that's the way to go, thanks :)

Comment: Have you found a solution? If so, update it in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a package like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to read the data from the .env file and use it in command-line.

I personally use something like this.

cmd:

> npm run VUE_CONFIG=foo

js:

```
if (process.env.VUE_CONFIG === 'foo') {
  require('foo.js')
} else {
  require('bar.js')
}
```

Comment: The question is asking how to point to vue config via environment variables. This does not answer the question.

Comment: OP is asking a suggestion. I've answered specifically for that and added my view. I dont see any problem with that

Comment: you dont need to rely on vue cli. Its a basic command line feature.